# Why does when I mess up something in an xml and do a clean, android studio still shows error?

Tags: android, xml

This is just a general question with regards to sometimes let's say you misspell something in an xml and it's like ok, you fix the spelling you click clean project and the error still shows up and that misspelled word you spell gets reverted back before you corrected it. It's like, what's the point of cleaning if it won't just won't take into account what I just fixed? This is just pure frustration.

Comment: So apparently I had my emulator out and I had to close the emulator hit clean then it worked. can someone explain why I have to do this?

Comment: do you use Instant Run?

Comment: Not really sure what that means but I run it in debug mode.

Comment: Actually all xml and object variable in java/android have a integer type reference variable. Which is automatically created on object create. So when you mispelled this the R.java file will not able to compile the code and code compilation is halted where it found an error. So to remove error from its stack or you need to clean it.

Comment: The thing is if I had my emulator open for some reason cleaning it literally didn't work for me. I had to close the emulator and hit clean. Not sure why.

Comment: No this must be some other issue. Have not seen this kind of error. Have worked on emulator a couple months ago. Now working on Genymotion emulator. But have not seen this issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

You might be making correction in the debug/layout/xyz.xml and not in your actual xml file.

Comment: no just editing it in the regular app/res/layout folder.